# AndroidStudio2.1 installed in windows10. It doen't work

Tags: android-studio

[image]

I clicked androidstudio icon, it does'nt work.
(I aloso installed JDK)

[image]

I set variable but it didn't work.
(I also set program files folder, but it didn't work too.)

Please teach me, what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Goto *Program files*>>*Android Studio*>>Right click on the Studio icon and start as admin. If this not works than try to run the 64bit application you will find in the same directory